# TakeWhile LINQ expression couldn't be translated

Tags: sqlite, linq, entity-framework-core

SQLite database table consists of four columns:

```
Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
Date = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
Axen = table.Column<bool>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
Doran = table.Column<bool>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true)
```

The goal is to get youngest rows (by `Date`) while `Axen` and `Doran` are true.

Following LINQ expression is used:

`return db.DayRecord.OrderBy(x => x.Date).TakeWhile(x => x.Axen == true && x.Doran == true).ToList();`

With expectation that rows are taken from the youngest (using `OrderBy`) while `Axen` and `Doran` are true.

Actual result is an error message saying:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The LINQ expression 'DbSet<DayRecord>()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
    .TakeWhile(x => x.Axen == (bool?)True && x.Doran == (bool?)True)' could not be translated.
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

While there is `ToList()` call at the end of statement the expectation is that query syntax is invalid.

What would be the valid syntax to achieve the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a linq query that can be translated to sql which is doing what you want(take rows until a condition is false). You either need raw sql or use Linq-To-Objects:

```
return db.DayRecord
    .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .TakeWhile(x => x.Axen == true && x.Doran == true)
    .ToList();
```

Because of the `AsEnumerable` everything in `DayRecord` is processed in memory.